# What is "durability" configuration in Hazelcast Durable Executor Service

Tags: hazelcast

What is "durability" configuration in Hazelcast Durable Executor Service?
The only documentation that I found is:
*durability: Durability of the executor.*

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Durability of the executor translates to backup-count a.k.a how many replicas of the task exist in the cluster, thus making the task durable to failures. In other words, if a node goes down then the task will be able to resume in another node in the cluster, without your manual intervention.